# question on accessing or getting specific google app script query parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I was wondering if I can access a specific query parameter from a method from activities.list API

specifically this piece of code

```
activity.events[0].parameters
```

I've already tried accessing through array like this:

```
activity.events[0].parameters[2]
```

but the output is not consistent, for instance index 2 is not what I need instead its a different query parameter. What I need is for example I need to access

> organizer_email

parameter specifically from the API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet)

I'll attach my sample code here. its from google api examples
(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/apps-script)

```
/**
 * List login events for a G Suite domain.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list
 */
function getData() {


  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');


  const userKey = 'all';
  const applicationName = 'meet';
  var pageToken;

  const optionalArgs = {
    maxResults: 10,
    pageToken: pageToken,

  };
  try {
    const response = AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey, applicationName, optionalArgs);
    const activities = response.items;
    if (!activities || activities.length === 0) {
      Logger.log('No logins found.');
      return;
    }
    // Print login events
    Logger.log('MEET LOGS:');
    for (const activity of activities) {
      Logger.log('(%s) %s %s', activity.events[0].parameters, activity.id.time, activity.id.time);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer)- Handle exception from the Report  API
    Logger.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

sample array / json result (2 results)

```
[
    {"name":"video_send_seconds","intValue":"40"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_bitrate_kbps_mean","intValue":"128"},
    {"value":"email_address","name":"identifier_type"},
    {"name":"audio_send_bitrate_kbps_mean","intValue":"2"},
    {"name":"video_send_packet_loss_max","intValue":"1"},
    {"value":"meetings_android_214151224321356190","name":"endpoint_id"},
    {"name":"device_type","value":"android"},{"intValue":"0","name":"video_send_packet_loss_mean"},
    {"intValue":"240","name":"video_recv_long_side_median_pixels"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_long_side_median_pixels","intValue":"1072"},
    {"name":"screencast_send_seconds","intValue":"0"},
    {"name":"video_send_fps_mean","intValue":"15"},
    {"intValue":"4","name":"audio_send_packet_loss_max"},
    {"intValue":"132","name":"video_recv_short_side_median_pixels"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"video_recv_packet_loss_mean"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_fps_mean","intValue":"8"},
    {"intValue":"1267","name":"audio_recv_seconds"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"network_congestion"},
    {"name":"network_estimated_download_kbps_mean","intValue":"1398"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"audio_send_packet_loss_mean"},
    {"name":"network_transport_protocol","value":"udp"},
    {"intValue":"1269","name":"duration_seconds"},
    {"intValue":"103","name":"video_send_bitrate_kbps_mean"},
    {"name":"identifier","value":"xxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxx.xxx"},
    {"intValue":"78","name":"audio_recv_packet_loss_max"},
    {"intValue":"10","name":"video_recv_fps_mean"},
    {"intValue":"3","name":"audio_recv_packet_loss_mean"},
    {"name":"network_recv_jitter_msec_max","intValue":"205"},
    {"name":"organizer_email","value":"xxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_short_side_median_pixels","intValue":"480"},
    {"name":"network_recv_jitter_msec_mean","intValue":"19"},
    {"name":"audio_send_seconds","intValue":"1267"},
    {"value":"xxxxxxxxxx","name":"display_name"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_packet_loss_max","intValue":"0"},
    {"name":"video_recv_seconds","intValue":"71"},
    {"intValue":"35","name":"network_rtt_msec_mean"},
    {"name":"video_send_long_side_median_pixels","intValue":"240"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_packet_loss_mean","intValue":"0"},
    {"value":"fjqip32o1ru139DFSA2wer23","name":"conference_id"},
    {"intValue":"883","name":"screencast_recv_seconds"},
    {"name":"product_type","value":"meet"},
    {"name":"network_estimated_upload_kbps_mean","intValue":"87"},
    {"name":"video_send_short_side_median_pixels","intValue":"132"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"video_recv_packet_loss_max"},
    {"name":"meeting_code","value":"ZXWEREHXSG"},
    {"name":"is_external","boolValue":true}
]
```

2nd result:

```
[
    {"name":"video_send_seconds","intValue":"0"},
    {"name":"identifier_type","value":"email_address"},
    {"name":"audio_send_bitrate_kbps_mean","intValue":"5"},
    {"value":"meetings_android_23adjfuhvioalu23xpiow;","name":"endpoint_id"},
    {"name":"device_type","value":"android"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"screencast_send_seconds"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"audio_recv_seconds"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"network_congestion"},
    {"name":"network_estimated_download_kbps_mean","intValue":"0"},
    {"value":"udp","name":"network_transport_protocol"},
    {"name":"duration_seconds","intValue":"9"},
    {"value":"xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxxxx","name":"identifier"},
    {"value":"xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.xxxxx","name":"organizer_email"},
    {"name":"audio_send_seconds","intValue":"7"},
    {"name":"display_name","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
    {"intValue":"0","name":"video_recv_seconds"},
    {"intValue":"30","name":"network_rtt_msec_mean"},
    {"name":"conference_id","value":"4ersdfgwe3re43edf3s"},
    {"name":"screencast_recv_seconds","intValue":"0"},
    {"name":"product_type","value":"meet"},
    {"name":"network_estimated_upload_kbps_mean","intValue":"0"},
    {"name":"meeting_code","value":"43eradsfdas23hgrf"},
    {"boolValue":true,"name":"is_external"}
]
```

Comment: Show sample array. You may need to use `Array.filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer

example usage:

```
activity.events[0].parameters.find(x => x.name ==='duration_seconds').intValue
```